# Understanding implicit arguments

Tags: syntax, verbs

We started learning about argument structure in my syntax class, and I am confused by implicit arguments, which our book hardly touches on.

What is the argument for a verb having an implicit argument vs. being a member of a different subcategory that has fewer arguments? The distinction here seems arbitrary, or at least based on semantics, not syntax.

Specifically under discussion is using *give* with only two arguments, when *give* is the prototypical trivalent verb.

> - He gives blood.
> - He gives to charity.

I assume the implicit arguments are something like "to the blood bank" and "things."

Note that this *isn't* my exact homework question, but an underlying one I'm asking to understand my actual question.

Comment: Since, as you say, it is hard to distinguish them by name or description, perhaps some examples of what are presented to be prototype implicit arguments would be helpful for us. I can think of several different ways to structure the distinction that would predict different outcomes. For instance, is _eat_ sposta have an implicit direct object, or is _rain_ sposta have an implicit subject, etc? A lot depends on what kind of arbitrary constraints you put on the constituent structure.

Comment: @jlawler "Give,"  which I edited into the post.

Comment: 'The distinction here seems arbitrary, or at least based on semantics, not syntax.' That's (close to) what my syntax professor said. 'He gives blood' means, compositionally, that he gives blood to anyone, with no regard to recipient; however, it's understood that he gives blood to the blood bank and not to his dog or to the police. The 'give' does, semantically, subcategorise for an indirect object, even though the indirect object isn't realised syntactically.

Comment: Though whether _give_ "subcategorizes for an indirect object" is not an observable matter, but rather a matter of how one defines subcategorization and how one identifies it -- and its absence -- in data. _Give_ is perhaps not the best verb to start with; it's a small verb (_give a push_) and participates in too many idioms (_give up, give out_). [An interesting set is  _buy, sell,_ and _pay_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf), which have local arguments (like specifying that one of the arguments may or must be money), and which contrast in several dimensions.

Comment: A "small" verb? And I agree, the examples in my textbook are half defensible as set phrases only.

Answer (score 2):

One way to find out whether a verb appears in two homophonous forms, with and without an 'implicit argument', or, on the contrary, the two homophonous forms correspond to **different lexemes** (= different homophonous verbs) and there are not any 'implicit arguments' involved, is to use the 'zeugma tests', and the easiest to apply in cases like the one you cite is (rightwards= R) 'R-gapping' [recall that leftwards 'gapping', L-gapping, is disallowed in SVO languages like English] subsequent to coordination - under the assumption that the R-gapped coordinate clause will only sound natural, rather than like a pun, when the omitted second verb is the **same** verb that occurs as an antecedent in the first coordinate clause and thereby licenses 'R-gapping'.

In the case of the verb(s) *give*, then, if you coordinate two clauses like *He **gives** blood* and *His wife **gives** to charity* and try to 'R-gap' the second token of *give*, the result, *He gives blood and his wife __ to charity*, is obviously zeugmatic (i.e., either unnatural, or interpretable only as a joke, with the structure [He [gives [blood and his wife](= DO) to charity]]), which suggests that the two tokens of *give* that appear in those two clauses belong to **different** lexemes (= different homonymous verbs *give1* and *give 2*), **not** that the first token of *give* is used with an 'implicit argument'.

Much the same happens with (dictionary)'verbs' like *drink* that can apparently be used either intransitively (= 'with an implicit argument?'), as in *He **drinks** (daily/too much)*, or transitively, as in *He **drinks** only beer*. In this case, the difference in meaning is more notorious, which points to the existence of two different lexemes (= two homophonous verbs *drink1* and *drink2*), but let's apply a couple of 'zeugma tests' anyway and see whether the results corroborate that intuition.

If we apply coordination followed by 'coordination reduction' (= CR), we get * *He **drinks** daily/too much and __ ___ only beer*, which is obviously zeugmatic (and plainly ungrammatical in this case). [Of course, we can save the construction by inserting a comma after the first coordinate, as in *He drinks too much **,** and only beer*, but that is no longer the coordination + CR test we are talking about here, but the addition of a **parenthetic** coordinate, which obeys rather different rules].

If we, instead, choose two parallel clauses with different subjects (say ***He*** drinks daily/too much and ***His wife*** drinks only beer) in order to be able to apply coordination followed by 'R-gapping', the result is * *He drinks daily/too much and his wife __ only beer*, which, again, is ungrammatical. Thus, in the case of *drink*, too, we should not say that the verb is used 'with an implicit argument' when intransitive; we must say that our lexicon contains at least **two** **different** homophonous lexemes, *drink1* and *drink2*, with considerable differences in meaning and syntactic behaviour.

Those are, perhaps, the simplest 'zeugma tests' lexicologists can use to determine whether any two tokens of a given 'form' are manifestations of the same lexeme or not, but there are other such tests, applicable to verbs as well as nouns (e.g., modification by adjuncts that may selectively apply to different 'facets' of a lexical concept represented by a unique phonetic-orthographic form). It would be too long to illustrate them all here, and it would lead us away from your question, but if you apply such tests in a systematic way, in principle you should always be able to decide whether an apparently unique 'verb' alternatively takes an argument explicitly and implicitly or, on the contrary, what happens is that the English lexicon contains two (or more) homophonous verbs with different adicity and more or less prominent differences in meaning.